# Selenium Webdriver Tutorials basic to advance

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am learning selenium webdriver on my own and can someone suggest me websites/videos which helps to teach selenium from basic to advance including framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.seleniumtests.com/p/free-selenium-training.html in java... deals with css, xpath, testNG, maven, jenkins. Easy to follow the person. Basic stuff but you can take it from there.

Lists most of CSS and XPATH locators in one page. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/